# How to permanently redirect to new domains startpage?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

If I wan't to redirect the whole site (from all pages) http://myoldsite.com to http://mynewsite.com I add this to myoldsites .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mynewsite.com/ [R=301]
```

That works fine, every page now goes to http://mynewsite.com.

But there is a problem, http://myoldsite.com/apage will go to http://mynewsite.com/apage. I wan't all pages to redirect to mynewsites startpage (http://mynewsite.com).

How can I do this?

Comment: Your rule already redirects everything to `mynewsites startpage (http://mynewsite.com).`

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth are you trying to do a permanent redirect with a rewrite rule?

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/  http://example.com
```

It's called a permanent redirect for a reason. The code 301 isn't for your average user, it's for search engines.

**EDIT:** `Redirect 301 / http://domain.com` redirects to a new location, but it also takes consideration for anything you've typed after the basic domain, for example a folder.

What you need to use is `RedirectMatch 301 ^/ http://example.com` which will redirect everything to `http://example.com`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didn't work. I still get the getvariable on the new page.

Comment: Then you've other problems. Mine works just fine. On two different servers.